# Pandoc fails to generate pdf from basic HTML page

Tags: html, linux, pdf, latex, pandoc

I'm trying to generate a PDF from a basic HTML page using pandoc, but it seems like a table (or a few) are preventing the PDF from being generated.

[This](https://bob.cs.sonoma.edu/IntroCompOrg-x64/bookch3.html) is the page I'm trying to convert to a PDF document. Here is the command that I'm running:

```sh
$ pandoc --verbose --from=html --to=pdf --output=ch3.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex -V geometry:margin=1.5in https://bob.cs.sonoma.edu/IntroCompOrg-x64/bookch3.html
```

And here is the end of the output generated:

```sh
Error producing PDF.
! Argument of \LT@nofcols has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.2588 \begin{longtable}[]{@{}r@{}}
```

I was able to save it as a markdown document, and then convert that markdown document to PDF, but the tables become a block of incomprehensible markdown text. I suspect that something is going wrong in the translation of the table elements, but I don't know anything about latex so I can't say for sure, and have no idea where to start debugging. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: what pandoc and xelatex versions are you using? (try the newest) and can you try narrowing it down to a specific table in the input document and post that one here?

Comment: can you show the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: Note that the website was generated from a TeX file. The cleanest, most efficient way of doing this might be to just write an email and ask for the source.

Comment: @mb21 I installed the latest versions via apt

Comment: @sam wouldn't it be too large for a SO post? It may be easier for you to run the command I posted and change the --to flag to latex

Comment: @tarleb how can you tell the site was made from a TeX file?

Comment: If you look at the page source, you'll find these two meta elements in the HTML head: `<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)">` and `<meta name="src" content="book.tex"> `. So we know that the author generated the page from a file `book.tex` with the help of the `tex4ht` tool.

Comment: @elliotwesoff unfortunately, apt doesn't have the newest pandoc version, see https://pandoc.org/installing.html

Comment: @elliotwesoff If it is too large to add to your question, you could share it via pastebin.com, github etc.